# Django Basic Manager

Tags: python, django

I'm using a [project](https://github.com/commadelimited/beginners-guide-to-django-rest-framework) to learn about the Django Rest Framework but came across this odd code (to me).

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    pass


class Author(models.Model):
    objects = AuthorManager()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I don't understand the purpose of `objects = AuthorManager()` and further, why we're using a manager that's simply doing a `pass`. Any reason for this?

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/      -  AuthorManager supposed to have create method , but not supposed to be in the model, so it's a mistake.

Comment: @dmitryro I don't understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

From Django's documentation:

> A Manager is the interface through which database query operations are provided to Django models. At least one Manager exists for every model in a Django application.

Here, the given model manager **AuthorManager** is not providing any methods so it is not making any sense.
In future, if we want to any method, we can include. Like, count the number of author's first name is 'qarthandso':

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def count_qarthandso(self):
        super(AuthorManager, self).get_queryset().filter(first_name='qarthandso').count()
```

and anywhere you can use like:

```
Author.objects.count_qarthandso()
```